# Protractor: How to select an element which has the same model than another one?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to build a selector for an element using protractor, but it turns out that this element has the same model that another element. When I inspect each element I get the following html:

Element 1:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-ng-model="account.accountType" data-ng-options="opt.code as opt.description for opt in bankPersonCtrl.catalogs.bank.bankAccountTypes"><option value="" disabled="" selected="" class="">Seleccione</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="Ahorros">Ahorros</option><option value="1" label="Corriente">Corriente</option></select>
```

Element 2:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-ng-model="account.accountType" data-ng-options="opt.code as opt.description for opt in bankPersonCtrl.catalogs.bank.bankAccountTypes"><option value="" disabled="" selected="" class="">Seleccione</option><option value="0" selected="selected" label="Ahorros">Ahorros</option><option value="1" label="Corriente">Corriente</option></select>
```

As you can notice, both have the same data-ng-model="account.accountType", so if I try to make a selector by model I can't.

I have read that it is possible to make a selector by css, but I do not know how to do it.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get the element by.repeater, so this works correctly for me:

```
function getBankAccountElement(index, name, isSpouse){
        if (typeof isSpouse === 'undefined'){
            isSpouse = false;
        }
        var bankAccounts = element.all(by.repeater('account in bankPersonCtrl.analysisPerson.bankAccounts'));
        if (isSpouse) {
            var bankAccounts = element.all(by.repeater('account in bankPersonCtrl.analysisSpouse.bankAccounts'));
        }
        return bankAccounts.get(index).element(by.model('account.' + name));
    }
```

and the way I am using it is:

```
this.getBankAccounts = function () {
        return {
            accountType: getBankAccountElement(0, 'accountType'),
            accountNumber: getBankAccountElement(0, 'accountNumber'),
            currentAverageAmmount: getBankAccountElement(0, 'currentAverageAmmount'),
            previousAverageAmmount: getBankAccountElement(0, 'previousAverageAmmount'),
            months: [getBankAccountElement(0, 'months[0]'), getBankAccountElement(0, 'months[1]'),
                        getBankAccountElement(0, 'months[2]')]
        };
    };
```